# The invocation of the constructor on the Cefsharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception

Tags: wpf, cefsharp

[image]

> Line number '81' and line position '18' ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could Not load file or assembly 'Cefsharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBroser.NoInliningConstructor()'.

It works on my machine, but when I release an EXE/MSI file and install to a machine of my client mechanic it throws the exception above.

Comment: Please no images of exceptions.  See https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Answer (score 2):

The `CefSharp` library requires the [Visual C++ Redistributables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads). Install them to your clients machine or add them as a prerequiste to you installer. Choose the appropriate redistributable for your version:

- CefSharp *65.0.0+* requires VC++ >= 2015
- CefSharp *51.0.0* to *63.0.0* requires VC++ 2013
- CefSharp *45.0.0* to *49.0.0* (.NET Framework 4.0) requires VC++ 2013
- CefSharp *43.0.0* and below (.NET Framework 4.0) requires VC++ 2012

If this does not help, check if all the files that are required are copied to your clients machine. Check [this list](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Output-files-description-table-(Redistribution)) for the required files for *CefSharp*. Compare the expected files from your build output folder to the installed files, because the exception clearly states that either `CefSharp.Core.dll` or one of its dependencies is missing.

There is a known issue that installers sometimes do not include *unmanaged* resources. If any resource or DLL is missing, then you have to manually add them to your setup.

Comment: Dear sir,
Cefsharp 75.1.142 in VC++ and  Visual Studio 2019 have my system an my Client System

Comment: @Parvezansari Updated the answer. Please check for missing files that are not included in your setup.